# AngularJS Linky set ng-click on all links

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm using [AngularJS linky filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) to make links on a snippet, and it works great, but I want to make call a custom function before executing the url.

So my question is, how can i set a ng-click attribute with linky filter ?

Hope it makes sense?

my code looks like:

```
<div class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="message in messages">

 <p class="message" ng-bind-html="message.message | linky:'_blank':open(url)"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this help to answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247251/angularjs-linky-filter-stoppropagation?

Comment: Nope .. as I see it, it only make the span clickable, i still want the a link to work, just want the a ng-click event on the link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from gtlambert's comment, it should work. I've used it before. If you add the following, it will run the alert first, and the proceed to follow the link:

HTML

```
 <p class="message" ng-bind-html="message.message | linky:'_blank':open(url)" ng-click="alertFunc()"></p>

</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.alertFunc = function() {
    alert("doSomething");
}
```

Comment: okay,,, but is not what i want ;) ... I want a custom click handler on all the links in a text - something like <a href="google.com">google</a> has to be equal to <a href="google.com" ng-click="open()">google</a>

Comment: in jquery I would do something like:: $("a").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})